# Avaya IP Office API Connection Fails to Close half the time

Tags: powershell, avaya

Avaya IP Office has a concurrent session limit of 2 per user. Using PowerShell, I use web requests to establish connections and perform tasks modifying users/extensions/hunt groups, etc. If I use Fiddler to detect a logout request in the Web Manager, I see that it sends a DELETE request to https://x.x.x.x:7070/WebManagement/ws/security/authenticate. However, when I replicate the request using PowerShell, it only works about half the time. The other half the time, I receive a 405 'Method Not Allowed' error message. I am not sure why it works sometimes and not others. Referring to Avaya's documentation, I haven't found a clear answer on what to do. I wouldn't be too concerned about it, since the session will time out after X minutes anyways, but it makes it very difficult for me to debug/test my scripting if I keep running into concurrent session limits because I don't know how to properly terminate my sessions via API calls.

Does anyone have experience working with Avaya IP Office API that could offer some insight into how to properly close out an established session without running into the 405 error?

If you need more clarification about what I am talking about, please ask what you are confused about.  Please don't just close the post.

Comment: Make sure you only have one connection.  Some servers will refuse a 2nd connection from same client.  HTTP uses TCP for the transport layer.  Make sure at the TCP layer you see the [FIN] and ack.  The connection may not be closing due to an exception.

Comment: Avaya allows up to 2 concurrent connections.  The 405 error seems to occur randomly,  but when it does, it will happen repeatedly for hours.  Even when there is only 1 active connection I see it happen.  Are you talking about using something like Wireshark to inspect the packets?  I've just been using Fiddler.

Comment: Two concurrent connection does not mean the two connection are from the same client.  Does code will work if you use two different clients?  Fiddler has a mode that does same as Wireshark.